# According to Quantum Mechanics, how are the particles classified?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, particle-physics

What exactly makes a particle classified as something within the scope of quantum mechanics?
Do the particles have to be subatomic or something more specific is needed to classify a particle as within the scope of quantum mechanics?

Comment: Particles are not quantized, some particles like the Z, W+, W- bosons, photons and the like are *themselves* the quanta of their respective fields.

Comment: The whole of Quantum and particle physics together deal in such quantum. Your answer is actually a full book on Quantum. Hence it's too broad to be answered by us.

Comment: @WrichikBasu I just wanted to know how quantum mechanics defines the word particle.

Comment: There is no such compact definition. At least I've never thought or heard about this thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TheBOI, here is a simpler way of thinking about this which I hope will answer your question. In my previous post I explained the chunkiness or "quantum nature" of things like spin and energy at atomic scales. what physicists call a "particle" then is a very, very tiny object which possesses a short list of well-defined attributes which are quantized: spin and and electrical charge are two such attributes. generically, those attributes are called quantum numbers and every particle in the subatomic zoo can be completely and unambiguously described by giving its quantum numbers.  Every electron in the universe has spin = 1/2 and charge = -1, for example.